# Using a batch file to extract text from one file into a new one

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with over 100 files, in these files contain text. I'm using this .bat code to extract certain text into another text file.

```
SETLOCAL
(FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,3) DO SET /P line=) < math.txt > lines.txt ECHO %line%
ENDLOCAL
```

This script only works for one .txt file per time. It needs to not only extract from mutiple files but to write again in multiple files in a sequence of file to file. When this is done I would like to run another script to input the extracted text into a programs form fields in a sequence of 1 file to 1 form. I've found a script to manipulate mouse clicks which will run the program but honestly this is over my expertise.

```
WshShell.Sendkeys "%f" (simulates clicking "File" on the menu bar)
WshShell.Sendkeys "n" (simulates clicking the "New" option on the "File" menu)
WshShell.Sendkeys "{Enter}" (simulates clicking "OK" to finish creating a new document in Word)
```

Answer (score 0):

OKay it seems you need to know the FOR command to choose which files to read (the .txt) but just have

```
type (insert input dir here) >> (insert ouput dir here)
```